# Ambiguity of a phrase in the Java specification documentation

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I have met the following text in the Java Specification

> Lines are terminated by the ASCII characters CR, or LF, or CR LF.
>   **The two characters CR immediately followed by LF are counted as one line terminator, not two**.

It is unclear whether the bolded text means the following combination of  the line termination symbols **CR LF CR LF** or just **CR CR LF**.

Comment: It means **CR LF**.

Comment: It simply means **CR LF**. Two characters (bytes) with ASCII value 13 and 10, which together make a single line termination.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552775/2071794

Comment: @Keepthesemind Would it be better to say something like "two pairs of CR LF immediately following each other are counted as one line terminator, not two"?

Comment: No, because that is not what is meant. AFAIK, **CR LF CR LF** _would_ be counted as two line terminators.

Comment: The term "two characters" refers to CR and LF, not two CRs and and one LF or two CR LF combinations.

Comment: By **CR** they mean **one** character which you, as a skilled programmer, know very well.

Comment: Let me make it clear using brackets: "The two characters (CR immediately followed by LF) are counted as one line terminator, not two."

Comment: @Keepthesemind In Russian you would write ""The two characters, CR immediately followed by LF, are counted as one line terminator, not two." But the English statement does not contain any syntactic separators,

Comment: It's not very well written.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You are correct. This could have used some such separators.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you're being too hard on Vlad.  As a non-native speaker, how is he to distinguish "The two characters CR immediately followed by LF" from "Two CR characters immediately followed by LF"? Or be sure that "CR immediately followed by LF" isn't a "character" in English, so that two of them would be CR LF CR LF?   One of the most interesting things about this site is discovering how everyday language structures can be so daunting to non-natives.

Comment: @remark I did agree that the spec is not very well written, but I am sure from sister sites, that Vlad is perfectly familiar with this computer topic and what it means, so it's almost a troll question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following would have been less confusing in the specification ...

> The following ASCII character sequences each act as one line terminator:
>
> - CR
> - LF
> - CR LF